# Pose is not remembered as Keyframe

Tags: animation, pose-mode

I use version 2.66 of Blender and I'm a newbie. I downloaded a free model of a human, rigged and skinned it and I try creating a simple animation. I set a pose, then press "I" and LocRot but when I do the same for the next pose the previous keyframe pose(s) become the same as the current. And when I press play not surprisingly see no animation. I see the created keyframes but they are the same. What I see in the Graph Editor is strange for me, because there are no interpolation lines between the frames(they are the same after all). I've tried lots of things. I've read about a similar problem but no solution.

Comment: Sounds indeed strange, could you upload a screenshot of the 3dview with the bones and the graph editor. Also are you sure you are in bone **Pose Mode** (you probably are or you couldnt pose the model)?

Comment: Something important to add. I use IK-bones to control the arms. Their positions are change in each frame, so animation works for them, but not for the bones that are parented to the IK-bones.

Comment: Here is a link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ReVjwDEgPhT3R5TkNSWlVkaWs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The problem is that all keyframes are the same no matter what I do.

Comment: Upload our file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, then other can help you more easily. Just edit your post and add the link to the file download.

Comment: You really should be using a newer version of Blender.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem is. When I'm in Pose Mode I have to pres "A" to select all animated bones. Then I have to press "I".